# HTML5 / Parallax suggestions?

Tags: jquery, html, css, parallax

Hey there a designer I work with really wants to incorporate the effect of this site:

https://snipcart.com/

Particularly the part where it says "how it works" and you scroll down and stuff is hidden but then appears.

I'm not sure how that's done though, I've tried to look for a few documentation techniques and such but there's not a wide selection on how to get that animation.  Can some kind soul steer me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about the sign up button?

Comment: How does this have anything to do with parallax scrolling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the effect is not that hard to create.

The way I did it:

1- The elements are hidden in css

```
#element{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

2- A jquery function checks how much of the page is scrolled on the page scroll

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var elemPosition = $('#element').offset().top,
        scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();

    //Checks if a little higher than element position (you can change 100 for whatever you want)
    if(scrollPosition - 100 > elemPosition){ 
        $('#element').animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 500); //OR the animation you want
    }  

});
```

That is pretty the basics of it all. Then you can set a starting state in css and animate it to something else in jquery.

Comment: hmm thanks do you have a quick demo of where I can see that?  Just not sure how to integrate that but I think I'm just missing something...  Thanks though that helps  Oh and thanks to the other people who commented too

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot that the way I did it is by animating the opacity like you can see on this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j5Cv6/1/) I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/ to achieve that effect.

Answer (score 0):

From hacking at the code, it's using TweenJS and Tiny Scroll.

http://www.baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/

http://createjs.com/#!/TweenJS